# React Native error - React: createElement: type should not be null

Tags: javascript, react-native, reactjs, native-base

I'm using [nativebase](http://nativebase.io/) as a base for the UI side of a React Native app that I'm developing and I'm running into an error with something that should be very simple.

I want to create a component for the tab footer of the app to include in different views as follows:

./Components/Footer.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Footer,
  FooterTab,
  Button,
  Icon,
  Text
} from 'native-base';

class TabFooter extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Footer >
        <FooterTab>
          <Button>
            <Badge>2</Badge>
            Apps
            <Icon name='ios-apps-outline' />
          </Button>
          <Button>
            Camera
            <Icon name='ios-camera-outline' />
          </Button>
          <Button active>
            Navigate
            <Icon name='ios-compass' />
          </Button>
          <Button>
            Contact
            <Icon name='ios-contact-outline' />
          </Button>
        </FooterTab>
      </Footer>
    );
  }
}

export default TabFooter;
```

And an example view would be:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Title, Content, Footer, FooterTab, Button, Icon,
  Text, List, ListItem, Input, InputGroup } from 'native-base';
import { TabFooter } from '../Components/Footer';

class EditGuest extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <Container>
        <Header>
          <Title>Whatever title</Title>
        </Header>

        <Content>
        </Content>
        <TabFooter />
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default EditGuest;
```

But when this view renders I'm getting the error:

```
ExceptionsManager.js:82 Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `EditGuest`.
```

Is there something really basic that I'm missing because I would of thought that I could just simply include this component within any view without any problems...

Comment: Try wrapping `TabFooter` in `View`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39839573/react-nativebase-not-showing-my-imported-components#answer-39877342

Answer (score 2):

Since you're doing a `default` export, you should remove `{}` from your `import`:

```
import TabFooter from '../Components/Footer';
```

see [Why es6 react component works only with "export default"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852933/why-es6-react-component-works-only-with-export-default)

Comment: Ok! One step closer... That got rid of the errors, but nothing is rendering. Is anything else jumping at you that I'm doing wrong?
Thanks for the resource, I'll have a read.

Comment: @oldo.nicho You seem to be missing an import for `Badge` but that should have thrown an error ...

Answer (score 2):

myFooter.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Footer, FooterTab, Button, Icon, Badge } from 'native-base';

class TabFooter extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Footer>
        <FooterTab>
          <Button>
            <Badge>2</Badge>
            Apps
            <Icon name="ios-apps-outline" />
          </Button>
          <Button>
            Camera
            <Icon name="ios-camera-outline" />
          </Button>
          <Button active>
            Navigate
            <Icon name="ios-compass" />
          </Button>
          <Button>
            Contact
            <Icon name="ios-contact-outline" />
          </Button>
        </FooterTab>
      </Footer>
    );
  }
}

export default TabFooter;
```

EditGuest.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header, Title, Content } from 'native-base';
import TabFooter from './myFooter';

class EditGuest extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header>
          <Title>Whatever title</Title>
        </Header>

        <Content />

        <View>
          <TabFooter />
        </View>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default EditGuest;
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Supriya! Hmmm, so all I had to do was wrap the `<TabFooter />` component within a `<View>` component. Odd... Why is this?

Comment: Yea I had a same question. You can anyway raise this issue on NativeBase GitHub.

Comment: Your question has been answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39839573/react-nativebase-not-showing-my-imported-components#answer-39877342

Comment: Sweet, thanks. As long as I know how to get around the problem, all good.
I'll raise an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change:

```
import { TabFooter } from '../Components/Footer';
```

to

```
import TabFooter from '../Components/Footer';
```