# ReactNative - Component not rendering when it's inside any other tag | NativeBase Custom Components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, es6-class, native-base

Trying to call the component class `GlobalHeader` from a separate file. 
**Problem** is, it won't display whenever it's in any other tag.

I've tried:

1. Adding a `StyleSheet` with `flex: 1` to the `Container`, `Header`
   and `GlobalHeader`
2. Removing `native-base` components and sticking with `react-native`
   components.
3. Toying around with `export default` (Doubt this is the problem)
4. Replacing the ES6 `import` with NodeJS `require`
5. Playing around with `GlobalHeader`'s structure (Putting containers in it and the like)

I can successfully call and render it here:

[image: Render successful]

If it's in another tag; yes, I've tried all sorts of tags:

[image]

Expected output (Yes, I know how to fix the icons):

[image]

Code for `Details.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Content, List, ListItem, Text, Header, Title, Button, Icon } from 'native-base';

import GlobalHeader from "../components/GlobalHeader";

export default class Details extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <GlobalHeader />
        <Content>
            <List dataArray={this.props.crate}
                renderRow={(item) =>
                    <ListItem>
                        <Text>{item}</Text>
                    </ListItem>
                }>
            </List>
        </Content>
      </Container>

        // <GlobalHeader />
    );
  }
}

module.exports = Details;
```

Code for `GlobalHeader.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Content, List, ListItem, Text, Header, Title, Button, Icon } from 'native-base';

export default class GlobalHeader extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (

        <Header>
          <Button transparent>
              <Icon name='ios-arrow-back' />
          </Button>

          <Title>Header</Title>

          <Button transparent>
              <Icon name='ios-menu' />
          </Button>
        </Header>

    );
  }
}

module.exports = GlobalHeader;
```

Help would be much appreciated. Not changing my routes/navigator. 
Only read about ES6 when I encountered this problem so it could be an ES6 problem?

Comment: Have you tried `import {GlobalHeader} from "../components/GlobalHeader";` ? Wrapping GlobalHeader with {}.

Comment: @philippsh Didn't work~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your example and the native-base [docs](http://nativebase.io/docs/v0.5.13/components):

> - NativeBase provides its own frame component, named after .
> - All the components should be included within the Container.
> - **Container takes mainly three components: < Header>, < Content> and < Footer>.**
> - Container comes with its predefined stylesheet, with an added advantage of accepting user-defined styles.
> - Usage of Container's Header component is very similar to your HTML . So is with Footer.
> - The Content component of Container is nothing but the body section of your screen.

But the Container Sees your component as GlobalHeader, not the native-base Header, so it ignores it.

At first I thought that if you move the Header out of the GlobalHeader up to the Details component, this would work, but unfortunately, native-base Header only accepts native-base Button and Title:

> - Header takes input as: Button and Title

So I don't think this will work..
I'm thinking of two options:

1. Embed GlobalHeader into Details.
2. If GlboalHeader is a simple
   component with no state, you can convert it into a function that
   returns the Header like so: (untested)

GlobalHeader:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Content, List, ListItem, Text, Header, Title, Button, Icon } from 'native-base';

export default function () {    
    return (
        <Header>
          <Button transparent>
              <Icon name='ios-arrow-back' />
          </Button>

          <Title>Header</Title>

          <Button transparent>
              <Icon name='ios-menu' />
          </Button>
        </Header>
    );
}
```

Details:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Content, List, ListItem, Text, Header, Title, Button, Icon } from 'native-base';

import getGlobalHeader from "../components/GlobalHeader";

export default class Details extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        {getGlobalHeader()}
        <Content>
            <List dataArray={this.props.crate}
                renderRow={(item) =>
                    <ListItem>
                        <Text>{item}</Text>
                    </ListItem>
                }>
            </List>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks :D Attempted this before posting here, but I couldn't call my function :'(

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered, please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39839573/react-nativebase-not-showing-my-imported-components#answer-39877342) and Issue [#297](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/297)

NativeBase as of now does not support custom components.

And this to be fixed with the rewrite of NativeBase