# Native Base components are showing blank page in react native android

Tags: react-native, native-base

Native base components showing blank page in react native android but when i am using react native components like View or Text then its work. Please help me. I think there are versioning issue.

Comment: Have you linked with `react-native link`?

Comment: yes and for confirmation i run it again @Li357

Comment: Finally i get solution, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39839573/react-nativebase-not-showing-my-imported-components this question helped me.